# Find all bugs without test cases

Tags: tfs

We have had a bunch of bugs input into TFS, but we are looking to build a query that will return all bugs that haven't been lined to a test case.

Anyone know how I would get that bug list?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to retrive these with a linked query:

1. Select **New Query...**
2. Select type **Work Items and Direct Links** (instead of **Flat List**)
3. Select **Bug** as the main work item type, and any other criteria you may need
4. Select **Test Case** as the type under **Filters for linked work items**
5. Finally, select **Only return items that do not have the specified links**